# Chain together multiple jQuery animations to progressively animate color

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, progress-bar, jquery-color

### Background

I am creating a progress bar with steps that animates as more steps are completed (wizard style where after each successive ajax request finishes it goes to the next step). A good example of the look I'm going for is Amazon's shipping tracking, pictured below.

[image]
I looked for plugins to do this, but I couldn't find one where I could add in the little circle steps like the image above, so I am creating my own with jQuery.

### Issue & Question

Currently the "best" way I can think to accomplish this is by chaining together multiple `.animate()` methods which apply a `background-color` to one after another DIVs in a row. My jQuery code looks like this:

```
$(function () {

    $(".progress-square:lt(1)").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#FABF03"
    }, 500, function () {
        $(".progress-square:lt(2)").animate({
            backgroundColor: "#FABF03"
        }, 500, function () {
            $(".progress-square:lt(3)").animate({
                backgroundColor: "#FABF03"
            }, 500);
        });
    });

});
```

and my HTML is rather simple:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="progress-bar-wrapper">
        <!--<div class="circle">put circle here</div>-->
        <div class="progress-square"></div>
        <div class="progress-square"></div>
        <div class="progress-square"></div>
        <div class="progress-square"></div>
        <!--<div class="circle">put circle here</div>-->
        <div class="progress-square"></div>
        <div class="progress-square"></div>
        <div class="progress-square"></div>
        <div class="progress-square"></div>
        <div class="progress-square"></div>
        <div class="progress-square"></div>
        <!--<div class="circle">put circle here</div>-->
    </div>
</div>
```

I am wondering if this is the correct way to "chain together" multiple `animate()` methods to successively animate one DIV after another? I seem to be having issues with my 4th `animate()` call using `:lt(4)` because the 4th `div` does not animate. I did not include this bit in the fiddle.

Or is there possibly a "shortcut" provided by jQuery or another plugin that helps with a case like this?

Currently in my fiddle i am using jQuery and [jQuery Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/) as well as Bootstrap is included to stay consistent with the project I am working on.

Here is a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jamez14/wkwg4obe/2/)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for all of those callbacks. This will work for any number of elements...

```js
$(function () {  
    $(".progress-square").each(function(i) { // i is the index of the current element in the collection
        $(this).delay(500*i).animate({ // create a delay that is multiplied by the current index
            backgroundColor: "#FABF03"
        }, 500)
    });
});
```

```css
.progress-bar-wrapper {
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.progress-square {
    background-color: gainsboro;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    width: 10%;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
        <div class="progress-bar-wrapper">
            <!--<div class="circle">put circle here</div>-->
            <div class="progress-square"></div>
            <div class="progress-square"></div>
            <div class="progress-square"></div>
            <div class="progress-square"></div>
            <!--<div class="circle">put circle here</div>-->
            <div class="progress-square"></div>
            <div class="progress-square"></div>
            <div class="progress-square"></div>
            <div class="progress-square"></div>
            <div class="progress-square"></div>
            <div class="progress-square"></div>
```

As an added bonus here is a version that turns the last element green as per your image... [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wkwg4obe/3/)